# Expression Engine - Where do I install EE2 Countdown Plugin?

Tags: expressionengine

Disclaimer: I have attempted to contact the developer about this plugin, but silence reigns.

I am trying to use the [EE2 Countdown plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee2-countdown) however, there are no instructions for how to install this plugin. I tried the normal way of uploading it to system/third-party/ but it does not show up. I also tried putting it in the plugin folder - no luck there either.

Any guidance on where to put this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **pi.countdown.php** file needs to be inside a folder called **countdown**.